# Airflow connection to MySQL

Tags: mysql, airflow

I would like do some ad hoc queries with my mysql database currently sitting on aws rds. I created a connection with all of the necessary credentials on the Airflow UI however the database did not show up under the Data Profiling>Ad hoc Query section.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: So ; did you try it again recently? Because what you describe doing should have worked fine.

Answer (score 6):

**For the original question, the OP may simply need to install a python-mysql adapter.**

I just ran into a similar issue.

For me, this issue was due to a lack of dependencies installed on my system.

As I was trying to connect to a Postgres database, I installed the python-postgres adapter, `psycopg2`:

`pip install psycopg2`

I restarted the Airflow web server, and Postgres connections began to populate within the Ad Hoc Query drop-down.

Here's how I identified this issue.

I was having this same problem trying to get a connection to an RDS Postgres server appear in the AdHoc query drop-down. After duplicating the existing `sqlite_default connection`, the drop-down appeared to include only Sqlite connections. This was with a near-vanilla default Airflow configuration. It seemed the connection was not listed because [`db.get_hook()` returned `None`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/2a55ffe0cd2c04fde2eecdbeff2fa727067069e1/airflow/www/views.py#L2044).

Stepping deeper into the code, I was able to identify that [`from airflow.hooks.postgres_hook import PostgresHook`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1f0a717b65e0ea7e0127708b084baff0697f0946/airflow/models.py) was failing with an error like:

`*** ImportError: No module named 'psycopg2'`

Using an interactive python debugger (eg. Pdb, via `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`), the OP may find a similar error message, ie:

`(Pdb) from airflow.hooks.mysql_hook import MySqlHook
*** ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb'`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this issue must be resolved by now. 
I follow these steps and able to run adhoc queries under data profiling.

1. Created a new connection under Admin tab.

   Defined Conn ID {any suitable name}

   Conn Type -- MySQL

   Hostname  -- cluster endpoint of MySQL on AWS RDS

   schema    -- MySQL schema where airflow table created.

   login/password -- as defined in while creating the database

   port --3306
   Save the above setting.

Now move to Data Profiling tab , the new connection will be available.